# Issue with capitalize first letter of textbox

Tags: jquery, textbox, capitalize

I am using the following code to capitalize the first letter entered into a textbox. Problem is when you tab to another textbox, then tab back and enter something, it will not erase what is there .. it appends what you type.

Can this be fixed?

```
$(function () {
    $('.userBox').on('DOMAttrModified textInput input keypress paste focus', 
      function (e) {
         $(this).val($(this).val().slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + 
                $(this).val().slice(1));
      });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VBXbz/8/

Comment: Does it need to be capitalized, or just presented as if it were capitalised? Also: not a 'textbox' (there's no such element), it's *either* a text-input (or `input` of `type=text`) or it's a `textarea`. If it's presentational there's always CSS: `textarea:first-letter { text-transform: uppercase; }`.

Comment: I would use css text-transforms, but I need the server end capitalized.

Comment: Then capitalize server-side, or in the `form`'s submit event; it's easier (and beyond user-manipulation at that point).

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function Capitalize(id) {
        var txt = document.getElementById(id);
        txt.value = txt.value.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) { return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase(); });
    }
</script>
```

Sarath@f1

Answer (score 0):

I would just bind focus to another function that will clear the contents of the input field. Like so:

```
$('.userBox').on('focus', function (e) {
    $(this).val("");
});
```

Then you'd essentially have http://jsfiddle.net/KWRef/.

Unless i missed some point you wanted to make?